# Is it possible to connect DB by a dongle IP?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm  using Java and MySQL.

I normally connect thorough by my static IP but I tried to connect to my database using my dongle. The dongle IP is not static. It is through, but I want to know is it possible to access a database when use a dongle for the Main Server.

Here is my code that I tried:

```
public class JDBC {


     public static Connection con() throws Exception {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"Dongle IP":3306/database", "root", "password");

            return c;

        }

        public void putdata(String sql) throws Exception {

            JDBC.con().createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);

        }

        public ResultSet getdata(String sql) throws Exception {
            Connection c = JDBC.con();
            ResultSet r = con().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
            return r;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Which machine is the dongle on? Is it on the one with the database, or the one you are connecting from? Also, when you say "it didn't work", what exactly do you mean? Error messages and stack traces are very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "dongle"? USB device attached as some kind of server that gets a dynamic IP?

Comment: @dcsohl I use My PC as the server machine. Laptop as a user. I want to use dongle to the PC(server machine). I bought a static IP and it is finely working. I want to know is there a way to access to  a server machine which used dongle?

Comment: @tadman Yeah. Is it possible to access using a dynamic IP. when I connect server machine to the internet  by the dongle, then I can find the dynamic IP. After that I placed that IP address to the above code. But it did not work.

Comment: What is this "dongle" thing you're talking about? Remember your external internet IP will not match your internal local IP. Can you use [Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) or something like it to advertise your server?

Comment: @tadman actually I have no good knowledge about this. And I got some thing from this comment of you.Thank you sir. I understood what you say. So may I know this please. when there is an external internet  IP and a local IP why can't use any code to access a database.? can't we use both of them and connect a database?

Comment: Your external IP is the one used by your router to communicate with the general internet. Your internal IP is likely a [non-routing IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) that is not directly accessible from the rest of the internet. These are two different things, but your access to the internet is made possible typically by using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on your router to map connections from private IPs to public IPs and vice-versa. You need to find your device's private IP, which is why Zeroconf helps.

Comment: @tadman Thank you sir. Your explaining is too much enough for me. Thank you sir.

Comment: Still having problems?